# What I'm having wrong with ES6 modules and SystemJS?

Tags: ecmascript-6, angular, systemjs

I was playing with [Angular2 beta tutorials](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html), and discovered how magnificient are ES6 new way of importing modules & systemjs.

However, there's a thing I can't make it to work.

Everything works fine, UNTIL you have second level page, system.js is configured only for 1st level page

here is plnkr with the issue http://plnkr.co/edit/afsJY6tzrSeYMOtzUnXQ?p=preview

once run, as you can see, homepage works but the second level page is not working.

Must be something with systemjs configuration, I have my explanations and I fully understand why it does not work, and I have found a workaround, but I don't like it, can you please point me to the correct way?

this part:

```
System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

could be easily fixed by using

```
System.import('/app/boot.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

but then there in the boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

I don't know how to fix the './app.component' because if I do '../app/app.component.js' then the typescript compiler blames, so, how's the correct strategy?

Comment: People are unlikely to download a zip file.

Comment: Agree with you, is there a way to have a "http-server" plunkr online?

Comment: edited the question with the plunkr

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the recommended way would be, as I'm still a beginner as well, but one way is to add maps to the config:

```
System.config({
  packages: {        
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  },
  map: {
    app: '../app' // <--
  }
});
```

You could of course replace the relative `../app` with something absolute like `/app` when you are running it locally.

Comment: interesting, could be a way, I have to add all possible relative paths for add? means ../app ../../app ../../../app and so on to a maximum of N levels?

Comment: Probably you could add an absolute path, like /app, right?

Comment: I can do for the boot without any problem, problem arise when I use the Es6 import, there I can't use absolute path, like import {AppComponent} from './app.component